# NameError: global name 'myLogFile' is not defined

Tags: python, global-variables

I have two functions, I have placed one of the functions into a seperate .py so I can import it, but I get an error when I try to run the script.

The function that I placed into the separate .py is:

```
def output_messaging(message):
    global myEmailText
    myLogFile.write(message)
    myEmailText = myEmailText + message
    print message
```

The script that I run has the following code:

```
def finish_process(errors):
    global myLogFile
    myLogFile.close()
    if errors == 0:
        myEmailHeader = "Subject: **"
    elif errors == 1:
        myEmailHeader = "Subject: **"
    else:
        myEmailDestination.append("**") 
        #myEmailHeader = "Subject: **"
    server = smtplib.SMTP(myServer) #email data log to nominated individuals
    server.sendmail(myEmailSender, myEmailDestination, myEmailHeader + "\n" + myEmailText)
    server.quit()
```

When I run the script i get the following error.

```
NameError: global name 'myLogFile' is not defined
```

myLogFile is declared lower down in the code (which is the location of the log file), but I'm slightly confused.

Thanks

Comment: If you showed us a complete, short example that demonstrates the problem, we'd be able to tell you what *exactly* the problem is...

Comment: File "D:\temp\UFRM\messaging.py", line 4, in output_messaging
    myLogFile.write(message)
NameError: global name 'myLogFile' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear. `myLogFile` is not defined anywhere in your `output_messaging` function. You need to define it in that function, or pass it in as a parameter.

You shouldn't be using globals anyway, they are almost always a bad idea. Pass parameters explicitly.

Comment: I've added global myLogFile in the output_messaging function, but its still giving me the same error.

Answer (score -1):

In `output_messaging`, you don't have `global myLogFile` to indicate that `myLogFile` is defined somewhere else in the file. When Python runs that function, it doesn't recognize the variable now.

Note that global variables are generally discouraged but that's a different discussion.